# Drop commits by commit message in `git rebase`

Tags: regex, git, terminal, git-rebase

I would like to do a `git rebase` and drop commits whose commit messages match a certain regular expression. For example, it might work like

```
git rebase --drop="deletme|temporary" master
```

And this would do a rebase over `master` while dropping all commits containing the string `deleteme` or `temporary`.

Is is possible to do this with the standard Git tool? If not, is it possible with a third-party Git tool? In particular, I want it to be a single, noninteractive command.

Comment: Someone's lookin for trouble ;)

Comment: You mean with unintended consequences?

Comment: try `filter-branch` which can do all that and more.

Comment: @PhilipOakley Could you possibly include an example of how you would do this with filter-branch? The git documentation is quite dense :-/

Comment: @PhilipOakley In particular, the docs for `--commit-filter` say

`For example, calling skip_commit "$@" will leave out the current commit (but not its changes! If you want that, use git rebase instead).`

So, since I want to skip the changes introduced by that commit, it would appear I can't use `filter-branch`. Is that correct?

Comment: @JeremyKun have a look at the man page for the "To remove commits authored by "Darl McBribe" from the history:" segment. Replace the `if [ condition]` with your desired search.

Comment: @JeremyKun Ah, I hadn't really noticed that part (the redirection to rebase). I was expecting that filter-branch should do it, as it is usually offered as the Swiss army knife of rewriting history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished using the same method as I used in [this answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/40118300/2747593).

First, we need to find the relevant commits. You can do that with something like:

```
git log --format=format:"%H %s" master..HEAD | grep -E "deleteme|temporary"
```

This will give you a list of commits with commit messages containing `deleteme` or `temporary` that are between `master` and your current branch. These are the commits that need to be dropped.

Save this [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script somewhere you can access it:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for sha in $(git log --format=format:"%H %s" master..HEAD | grep -E "deleteme|temporary" | cut -d " " -f 1)
do
  sha=${sha:0:7}
  sed -i "s/pick $sha/drop $sha/" $@
done
```

Then run the rebase as:

```
GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=/path/to/script.sh git rebase -i
```

This will automatically drop all commits that contain `deleteme` or `temporary` in their commit message.

As mentioned in my other answer:

> [This script won't allow] you to customize what command is run to calculate which commits to use, but if this is an issue, you could probably pass in an environment variable to allow such customization.

Obligatory **warning**: Since a rebase rewrites history, this can be dangerous / disruptive for anyone else working on this branch. Be sure you clearly communicate what you have done with anyone you are collaborating with.

Comment: It appears that `git log --format=format:"%H %s" master | grep -E "deleteme|temporary"` includes all commits (including those on master). Could you amend this to only output the commits on the current branch (as compared with master)?

Comment: I think maybe `git log HEAD...master`?

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks.

Comment: See also [What are the differences between double-dot “..” and triple-dot “…” in Git commit ranges?](//stackoverflow.com/a/463027/2747593) You want `..` in this case, because you don't want to include new commits on `master` that aren't on your current branch.

Comment: This solution doesn't quite work, because `git rebase -i` doesn't include the full SHA hashes. You can replace both `$sha` with `${sha:0:7}` in the sed command to make it work. Thanks again!

Comment: @JeremyKun: Oops, not sure how I missed that.  I even ran into a problem related to that when working on my other answer, but I somehow forgot to fix it.  Updated my answer, thanks!

Comment: Am I the only person who thinks that using *interactive* rebase for "headless automation" is insane?

Comment: `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=/path/to/script.sh git rebase -i` won't work as expected. It will rebase only the last commit (HEAD). In order to rebase from master you'll need to add `master` at the end. 

Like this: `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=/path/to/script.sh git rebase -i master`

Answer (score 1):

You could e. g. use interactive rebase. So do `git rebase -i <first commit that should not be touched>`, and then in vim where you have the list of commits, you can do `:%s/^[^ ]* \([^ ]* issue\)/d \1/g` to use drop stanza for all commits whose commit message starts with `issue`. But be aware that `git rebase` is not working optimally with merge commits. By default they are skipped and the history flattened, but you can try to keep them with parameters.

Comment: I should have been more specific, I want to automate this process headlessly.

Comment: Then use a non-interactive editor like in `git -c core.editor='sed -i "s/^[^ ]* \([^ ]* issue\)/d \1/g"' rebase -i <first commit to leave untouched>`. Same effect as above, without any manual interaction.

Answer (score 0):

[@Scott Weldon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2747593/scott-weldon)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41753506/12206312) works great for this usecase, however If the regex checks from the start of the message for example with `(^(deleteme)|^(temporary))`, then this won't work, since the start of the grep is the commit hash. So in that case you can use this instead

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for sha in $(git log --format=format:"%s %H" master..HEAD | grep -E "^(deleteme)|^(temporary)" | awk '{print $NF}')
do
  sha=${sha:0:7}
  sed -i "s/pick $sha/drop $sha/" $@
done
```

The core difference is that `%s`and `%H` swapped places, and therefore we search the last part of the string instead of the first part of the string by piping to `awk '{print $NF}')`

Also worth noting that this is called the same way as in Scott Weldon's answer:

```bash
GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=/path/to/script.sh git rebase -i master
```